# Calculate the ideal mix give data with uncertainties

Tags: python, optimization, uncertainty

I have a sample (C) with a given elemental isotopic ratio. It is the mixture of elements from two different populations (A and B) which have different isotopic ratios. For each population A and B I have measured the isotopic ratios (Ax and Bx) in each population and have their error (Ae and Be). Also, note that I have multiple samples in each population (the different values in vector Ax, for instance). How do I calculate the ideal weighting (w) with the given information.

I assume that the equation I want to solve is C=wA+(1-w)B. If I perfectly knew A, B and C, I could easily rearrange for w. However, because I have different samples, what is the ideal way to calculate the value of w?

One way I have tried is to minimize the above equation using a chi squared approach. My python code is

````py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

Ax = [12, 15, 17, 13, 9]  # weight
Ae = [1, 2, 2, 1, 4]      # error
An = len(Ax)

Bx = [73, 77, 72, 81, 70] # weight
Be = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2]      # error
Bn = len(Bx)

Cx = 54 # weight
Cy = 0  # error
Ce = 2

yp = np.zeros(An)

n = An*Bn
LHS = np.zeros(n)
RHS = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(An):
    for j in range(Bn):
        k = i*Bn+j
        LHS[k]=Cx/Ce-Bx[j]/Be[j]
        RHS[k]=Ax[i]/Ae[i]-Bx[j]/Be[j]

def chisqfunc(a):
    model = a*RHS
    chisq = np.sum(((LHS - model))**2)
    return chisq

w0=0.5
w=opt.minimize(chisqfunc, w0)
print(w)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.errorbar(Ax, yp, xerr=Ae, fmt='o', color='black', ecolor='lightcoral', elinewidth=3, capsize=0);
ax.errorbar(Bx, yp, xerr=Be, fmt='o', color='black', ecolor='dodgerblue', elinewidth=3, capsize=0);
ax.errorbar(Cx, 0, xerr=Ce, fmt='o', color='black', ecolor='purple', elinewidth=3, capsize=0);
```
````

Comment: Like I said yesterday, I would see this as a calculus minimization problem. You may not be able to get exactly $C$, but maybe some $w$ gets you very close.

Comment: My problem with using calculus here is that I do not know how I would do so given the uncertainties. If you think it is an option, please highlight how to do that in this instance? Thanks.

Comment: What are the weights and errors in your code?

Comment: Xe is measurement error for each sample where X can be A, B or C. Xx is the measured weight where X can be A, B or C. Given the sample and errors, I want to find the optimal w.

Comment: 1) You don’t have an Xe in your code. 2) What is a measurement error? If you know the measurement error, then you know the measurement.

Comment: The errors are Ae, Be and Ce. For example, there are five sample of A with meausred weights [12, 15, 17, 13, 9] and uncertainties on these measurments are [1, 2, 2, 1, 4] . I also have five samples from B. I want to know the weight needed to make C which has weight Cx and measured error Ce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102363/discussion-between-dave-and-js16).

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica unfortunately it does not from my perspective. I assume you mean does the form $w=\frac{C-B}{A-B}$ solve the problem. It would if I perfectly knew A, B and C. However, I do not perfectly know them. I have five samples of group A, each with measurment uncertainty, five samples from group B with measurement uncertainty on each and one from C. My question is how to estimate w in this sense.

Comment: Perhaps I could use chi squared minimization with uncertianty as I tried in the code, but it seems to not work or I made an error. Maybe I'll write out the equation I tried to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

First I calculate the mean and standard deviation from the samples in A and B. Then I calculat the weight as w=(C-B)/(A-B). This gives me a crude estimate of what w should be.

A more complex way is to assume A and B are distributed normally, and then I can generate samples from them using the mean and standard deviation I calcuated. Say I generate 1000 points from A and B, looping through these 1000 points I can test different weights, keeping those that are successful. After loop through all 1000 combinations, I can plot a histogram of weights to see which has had the most successes. I did this and it turns out that the crude way is close to the numerical way, so I am satisfied with that. I can post an example if needed.

If anyone thinks of a different solution, please let me know.